# How to link other websites within HTML tag

Tags: html, css

As for today March 2017,
I asked this question without doing proper research at early "beginner stage" of my HTML career, I've now with more experience know the solution: The answer to my own question is simply to use iframe, here is the link: 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <body>
    <nav><code for navigation bar...></nav>
     <Website here, how?>
  </body>
 </head>
</html>
```

Kind regards, 
Dler.

Comment: try using HTML iframe tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can use an iframe

```
    <iframe src="page.html" width="300" height="300">
      <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
      <a href="page.html">Visit the page</a>
    </iframe>
```

Comment: That isn't helpful fallback text. Put something useful in there, like a link to the document.

Answer (score 0):

You could insert an `<iframe>` and have your `navigation bar` target the name of that `<iframe>`.

Answer (score 0):

An other idea would be to create an html file containing your navigation bar and an other one containing the main web page and then include it with php
For example

Html file:navigation.html

```
   <nav>
    <!---your navigation code-->
    </nav>
```

your main page body.html

Index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
     <head>
      <body>

      <?php include'navigation.html'?>
      <?php include'body.html'?>
      </body>
     </head>
    </html>
```

Or you can use iframes

Comment: not really that good of an answer, as .php files take longer to load. thats what iframes are for

Comment: Depending on the situation, iframes may take longer to load (since you have to deal with two HTTP requests instead of one). They also introduce usability issues since there are multiple scrolling regions (this is especially problematic on small touch screens) and a more complicated browser history (for use with back/forward).